# How can I make a borderless c# form not remove focus from another window upon interaction

Tags: c#, forms, keyboard

I'm looking for a way to keep my C# Form from removing focus from other windows when the user interacts with it. Basically, I'm trying to create a custom on-screen keyboard, and I want to be able to hit the keys with my mouse or Leap Motion without removing focus from the window I'm trying to type in.

-Overriding "ShowWithoutActivation" does not work. I tried using:

```
protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
{
    get { return true; }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: TopMost = true; FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: He wants to keep (keyboard) focus both on his app and the target program. I think it is possible but not without hooking into the internals.. Maybe a search for _keyboard hook_ will help?

Comment: @TaW put me on the right track. The solution was to add keyhooks.